# Dual quaternion derivation

Tags: derivatives, quaternions

I'd like to derivate a dual quaternion

\begin{align}
\hat{q}&=(1 + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon\vec{t})q
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
q &= e^\vec{w} , \\\vec{w}&=(0, w_1,w_2,w_3)^t
\end{align}
is a quaternion in exponential map representation that describes a rotation like:
\begin{align}
q &= (\cos(\frac{1}{2}\theta), \vec{u}*\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta)) 
\end{align}

I'd like to get 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat{q}}{\partial \vec{w}} &= (1 + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon\vec{t}) \frac{\partial q}{\partial \vec{w}} &(1)\\
\frac{\partial q}{\partial \vec{w}}&=(\frac{\partial q}{\partial w_1},\frac{\partial q}{\partial w_2},\frac{\partial q}{\partial w_3})
\end{align} 
where the derivation in the last line consists of 12 partial derivations and returns a 4x3 matrix.

Getting to this point I'm not sure about how to finish the multiplication in (1), which consists of a dual quaternion and a 4x3 matrix.

Or is there another common way to derivate a dual quaternion?

Please could anyone solve this?
Thank you for any hints!

Comment: The verb for "take the derivative" is "[differentiate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/differentiate?s=t)." Which function are you looking at? $\hat{q}$ as a function of $\vec{t}$?

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking at \hat{q}

Comment: ... as a function of $\vec{t}$, right?

Comment: as a function of \vec{w}. This vector contains the angles \theta_i, the only variable of \hat{q}

Comment: So $\hat{q}=(1 + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon\vec{t})e^\vec{w}$ as a function of $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{t}$ is fixed?

Comment: that's it, right!

Comment: Is $\vec{t}$ an arbitrary quaternion, or is it possibly simpler somehow?

Comment: actually its a quaternion representing a vector, as \vec{t}=[0,t_x,t_y,t_z]. This has to be because it's the dual part of the dual quaternion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying: I don't know how to use the dual quaternions, so this is all new to me. It seems this is, fundamentally, a function of $\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^8$, after you unravel it.

Comment: What do you have here?  Some kind of 4-dimensional vector space with metric signature $(0, +, +, +)$, so you need to do not only rotations among the spatial dimensions, but transformations that mix spatial dimensions and the degenerate dimension?

Comment: Let's split the question: 1) a quaternion $q = (\cos(\frac{1}{2}\theta), \vec{u}*\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta)) = w_0+w_1*i+w_2*j+w_3*k$ is to be derived w.r.t. a vector $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$

Comment: ...and we get 3 partial derivatives, namely $\frac{\partial q}{\partial v_1},\frac{\partial q}{\partial v_2},\frac{\partial q}{\partial v_3}$ which are quaternions again. Is this a matrix now or what form of mathematical construction?

Comment: Hey I just solved this! I'll be able to handle my problem without this question. Thank you all!

Comment: Could you please post some more details about your solution? Maybe it is of interest to someone, how to get around this problem.